# @Autowire failing in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to autowire a class in Spring boot application. But Spring is not giving any instance, it is giving null.

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

public JWTAuthorizationFilter( AuthenticationManager authManager )
{
    super(authManager);
}

@Autowired
private JWTUtil jwtUtil;
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain )
        throws IOException, ServletException
{
    String jwt = req.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);

    if( jwt == null || !jwt.startsWith(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX)  )
    {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
        return;
    }
    if(!jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt))
    {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
        return;
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
}
```

The `JWTUtil jwtUtil` is getting null value. I have marked `JWTUtil.java` with `@Component` annotation, but still it is not working.

```
@Component
public class JWTUtil {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JWTUtil.class);
@Autowired
private  UserModelRepository userModelRepository;

public  Boolean validateToken( String jwt )
{
    Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SecurityConstants.SECRET)
            .parseClaimsJws(jwt.replace(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX, "")).getBody();

    Date createdAt = claims.getIssuedAt();
    String mobileNumber = claims.getSubject();

    Optional<UserModel> userModelOptional = userModelRepository.findByMobileNumberAndIsActiveTrue(mobileNumber);
    if( !userModelOptional.isPresent() )
    {
        return false;
    }
    UserModel userModel = userModelOptional.get();
    Calendar logoutTime = userModel.getLogoutTime();
    if( null != logoutTime )
    {
        Date logoutDate = logoutTime.getTime();
        if( logoutDate.before(createdAt) ) // new token
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    logger.info("Invalid token....issued before last logout");
    return false;

}
}
```

Here also

`@Autowired
private  UserModelRepository userModelRepository;`

is getting null. Why is this happening?

**Edit**
Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan( "com.highpeak.gbi.datastore.model" )
@EnableJpaRepositories( "com.highpeak.gbi.datastore.repository" )
@ComponentScan( { "com.highpeak.gbi.webservices",     "com.highpeak.gbi.datastore" } )
public class Application {

public static void main( String[] args )
{

    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder()
{
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

}
```

Comment: auto wired fields cannot be `null` they can only be null if you are creating instances of beans outside the scope of Spring. So let me guess you are doing `new JWTAuthorizationFilter` inside your `http` method of the Spring Security configuration.

Comment: Try adding @Component on JWTAuthorizationFilter

Comment: It's a Util class, right? Make methods static. Don't inject. It's ugly

Comment: @NicoVanBelle I did that. But I am not able to Autowire `@Autowired
private  UserModelRepository userModelRepository;` in that case

Comment: @M.Deinum You are right I am using `new JWTAuthorizationFilter` inside your `http` method of the Spring Security configuration. What should I do now?

Comment: That logic should be done afterwards because whether the actual JWT token is valid or not is actually not dependant on a valid and active mobile number.

Comment: Move that to a `@Bean` method.

Comment: I will try that. But why I am spring not able to autowire?

Comment: What is your package setup? Where is your `SpringBootApplication` placed?

Comment: Package setup added in the question. Please refer the edit